# getting Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) while using SPServices()

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin, spservices, sharepoint-calendar

here am trying to get reccurring events from calendar list with the help of SPServices i have a code as shown bellow,but when am using the bellow code it is giving me erroe as

**"https://MYURL/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)send @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5"**  
 and it also shows WARNING as

**"jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/."**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {         
            var start = new Date();
            $().SPServices({
                operation: "GetListItems",
                async: false,
                listName: "ListName",
                CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields>" +
                          "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
                          "<FieldRef Name='EventDate' />" +
                          "<FieldRef Name='EndDate' />" +
                          "<FieldRef Name='Location' />" +
                          "<FieldRef Name='Description' />" +
                          "<FieldRef Name='fRecurrence' />" +
                          "<FieldRef Name='RecurrenceData' />" +
                          "<FieldRef Name='fAllDayEvent' />" +
                      "</ViewFields>",
                CAMLQuery: '<Query>' +
                      '<CalendarDate>' + start + '</CalendarDate>' +
                      '<Where>' +
                          '<DateRangesOverlap>' +
                          '<FieldRef Name="EventDate" />' +
                          '<FieldRef Name="EndDate" />' +
                          '<FieldRef Name="RecurrenceID" />' +
                          '<Value Type="DateTime">' +
                              '<Year />' +
                          '</Value>' +
                          '</DateRangesOverlap>' +
                      '</Where>' + '<OrderBy>' +
                          '<FieldRef Name="EventDate" />' +
                      '</OrderBy>' +
                      '</Query>',
                CAMLQueryOptions: '<QueryOptions>' +
                          '<CalendarDate>' + start + '</CalendarDate>' +
                          '<RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>v3</RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>' +
                          '<ExpandRecurrence>TRUE</ExpandRecurrence>' +
                      '</QueryOptions>',
                completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                    var events = [];
                    //        alert(xData.responseXML.xml);
                    alert($(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName=rs:data]").attr("ItemCount"));
                    $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName=z:row]").each(function () {
                        var fADE = $(this).attr("ows_fAllDayEvent");
                        if (fADE != null) {
                            if (fADE == 0) { thisADE = false }
                            else thisADE = true;
                        }
                        var thisID = $(this).attr("ows_ID");
                        var sepID = thisID.indexOf(';#');
                        if (sepID != -1) thisID = thisID.substring(0, sepID);
                        var thisTitle = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
                        var thisRecurrence = $(this).attr("ows_fRecurrence");
                        var thisDesc = $(this).attr("ows_Description");

                        if (thisID.length > 3) alert(thisTitle + ": " + thisID);
                        var thisUrl = "DispForm.aspx?ID=" + thisID + "&Source=FullCalendar.aspx";
                        var thisRD = $(this).attr("ows_RecurrenceData");

                        events.push({
                            //          className: ownerClass, \\Will be an @attrib in the responseXML
                            title: thisTitle,
                            start: $(this).attr("ows_EventDate"),
                            end: $(this).attr("ows_EndDate"),
                            allDay: thisADE,
                            url: thisUrl,
                            description: thisDesc
                        });

                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

[image]

Comment: Is the path to jquery file correct ? Looks like you are having problem loading jquery file.

Comment: yes the path is correct because this path related issue arises only when am running this code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of accessing the all Recurrence Event from calendar List using the JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    $(".readItem").click(function(){
    var html="";
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "/sites/demo/Style%20Library/cascade/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"; 
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    var start = new Date();debugger;
    $().SPServices({
                    operation: "GetListItems",
                    async: false,
                    listName: "Calendar",
                    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields>" +
                              "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
                              "<FieldRef Name='EventDate' />" +
                              "<FieldRef Name='EndDate' />" +
                              "<FieldRef Name='Location' />" +
                              "<FieldRef Name='Description' />" +
                              "<FieldRef Name='fRecurrence' />" +
                              "<FieldRef Name='RecurrenceData' />" +
                              "<FieldRef Name='fAllDayEvent' />" +
                          "</ViewFields>",
                    CAMLQuery: '<Query>' +
                          '<CalendarDate>' + start + '</CalendarDate>' +
                          '<Where>' +
                              '<DateRangesOverlap>' +
                              '<FieldRef Name="EventDate" />' +
                              '<FieldRef Name="EndDate" />' +
                              '<FieldRef Name="RecurrenceID" />' +
                              '<Value Type="DateTime">' +
                                  '<Year />' +
                              '</Value>' +
                              '</DateRangesOverlap>' +
                          '</Where>' + '<OrderBy>' +
                              '<FieldRef Name="EventDate" />' +
                          '</OrderBy>' +
                          '</Query>',
                    CAMLQueryOptions: '<QueryOptions>' +
                              '<CalendarDate>' + start + '</CalendarDate>' +
                              '<RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>v3</RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>' +
                              '<ExpandRecurrence>TRUE</ExpandRecurrence>' +
                          '</QueryOptions>',
                    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                        var events = [];

                     alert(Number($(xData.responseXML).find("rs\\:data, data").attr("ItemCount")));
                        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
                            var fADE = $(this).attr("ows_fAllDayEvent");
                            if (fADE != null) {
                                if (fADE == 0) { thisADE = false }
                                else thisADE = true;
                            }
                            var thisID = $(this).attr("ows_ID");

                            var thisTitle = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
                            var thisRecurrence = $(this).attr("ows_fRecurrence");
                            var thisDesc = $(this).attr("ows_Description");


                            var thisUrl = "DispForm.aspx?ID=" + thisID + "&Source=FullCalendar.aspx";
                            var thisRD = $(this).attr("ows_RecurrenceData");
    alert("Title:"+thisTitle+"\n"+"Start Date:"+$(this).attr("ows_EventDate")+"\n"+"EndDate:"+$(this).attr("ows_EndDate"));
    html+="<p>"+thisTitle+"</p><p>"+$(this).attr("ows_EventDate")+"</p><p>"+$(this).attr("ows_EndDate")+"</p>";


                        });
                        $(".items").html(html);

                    }

                });
                });
                });

    </script>​​​
```